# openmp reduction of multidimentional arrays in fortran

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, openmp, reduction

I have these loops here where I calculate array 'tab'. 
I tried using the openmp reduction but it doesn't work. I get a seg. fault with OMP_NUM_THREADS greater than 1.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) &
!$OMP PRIVATE(ii,ix_tab,iy_tab,ipx,ipy,iw,C) &
!$OMP REDUCTION(+:tab)
do ii = 1,N

    ix_tab = ...
    iy_tab = ...

    do ipy = -npy_max,npy_max
        do ipx = -npx_max,npx_max
            do iw = 1, M
                C = Fx(iw,ipx,ix_tab) * Fy(iw,ipy,iy_tab)

                tab(iw,ipx,ipy) = tab(iw,ipx,ipy) + A(iw,ii) * C
            enddo
        enddo
    enddo

enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

--- EDIT ---

Ok, here is my solution:

```
allocate wrk(nt,-npx_max:npx_max,-npy_max:npy_max,nthreads)

!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) &
!$OMP PRIVATE(tid,ii,ix_tab,iy_tab,ipx,ipy,iw,C)

tid = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() + 1

!$OMP DO
do ii = 1,N

    ix_tab = ...
    iy_tab = ...

    do ipy = -npy_max,npy_max
        do ipx = -npx_max,npx_max
            do iw = 1, M
                C = Fx(iw,ipx,ix_tab) * Fy(iw,ipy,iy_tab)

                wrk(iw,ipx,ipy,tid) = wrk(iw,ipx,ipy,tid) + A(iw,ii) * C
            enddo
        enddo
    enddo

enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

do  tid = 1, nthreads
    tab(:,:,:) = tab(:,:,:) + wrk(:,:,:,tid)
enddo

deallocate(wrk)
```

Can it be done better? faster?

Regards.

Comment: Your stack is probably overflowing... You should consider implementing the reduction yourself!

Comment: Simply make `tab` an `ALLOCATABLE` array. Otherwise `REDUCTION` makes multiple private copies of it and many compilers tend to place those private copies on the stack even when they are bigger than the threshold for automatic heap allocation.

Comment: @VladimirF: The original code in the other question contained data races that probably resulted in out-of-bound array access. If I read the timeline correctly, he applied the `reduction` clause before fixing the data race issue. In any case, the OpenMP standard states that `reduction` works as `private` when it comes to data allocation, i.e. it should create allocatable private copies of allocatable list items.

Comment: Ok, I accept ths. But as there is no.race condition in that question now you could have just answeered it eith a better answer, now they are exact dupkicates IMHO. And I am pretty sure there are others in the history.

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558318/openmp-segmentation-fault-11 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870564/gfortran-openmp-segmentation-fault-occurs-on-basic-do-loop

Comment: I considered carefully the similarity. Still, there is no indication that in the current state of the code the OP of the other question is still getting segmentation fault when the `reduction` clause is used. But the culprit in the second of the two questions you suggest is the same.