# Best way to handle large private arrays in openmp parallel region

Tags: arrays, fortran, openmp

I am using OpenMP with Fortran.

Within an OpenMP parallel region `private` variables are allocated on the stack. I have some variables that are 1000x1000 arrays and this is causing some problems. I can get round it but I seem to have to do `ulimit -s unlimited` as well as setting `OMP_STACKSIZE` environment variable. This is OK for me, but not great for other users of my code.

At the moment I have arrays passed in the old fashioned way:

```
integer, intent(in) :: N
real(c_double) :: private_var(N,N)

!$omp parallel do default(shared) private(private_var)
...
```

Is there a better way to declare these arrays that avoids users having to manually set the stack size on their machine? I don't want to allocate within the loop, but perhaps I can open the parallel region first, have each worker allocate their own private work array, the have the do loop?

Comment: Make the arrays allocatable. There are several duplicates about this here.

Comment: You might find the second part of [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13561722/1374437) helpful.

Comment: Another one very detailed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code?lq=1

Comment: Vladimir - thanks. I had seen that one which is how I know about changing the stack size. But the question here was a bit different - how to allocate the arrays so that changing the stack size is not required. The duplicate you marked answers that though (I hadn't found that)

Comment: @casey, I don't think `heap-arrays` has any effect on openmp private variables.